# What is a battery's function in a tesla coil?

Tags: batteries

What does a 9v battery do? I dont understand why a battery has to be used. Does the coil just transfer the battery's charge from the battery to a wireless emission through the coil?

Comment: Context? Tesla coils don't contain batteries. Some people build small battery-*powered* ones.

Comment: So a tesla coil that produces electricity can be built without batteries? I want to build one but i always thought you could do so without a battery.

Comment: Presumably you need some sort of power source. Battery. Mains power supply. Something. Otherwise there is nothing to power the coil.

Comment: Coils store energy with current until limited by ohm's law and release by arc 1/2LI^2 watt-sec = Joules

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I admit i know very little about electronics. So can a telsa coil not operate without an external power source?  I thought the whole point was to create a power source independent of the power grid?

Answer (score 4):

Your question makes no sense since it relies on a false premise.

A Tesla coil is basically a resonant transformer with high step-up ratio and resonance usually in the RF frequency range.  A battery is not part of a Tesla coil.

The circuit that drives a Tesla coil has to be powered somehow, and the power source could be a battery.  However, that is not inherent to a Tesla coil.

Answer (score 0):

A battery powered Tesla coil would be powered by the battery. A mains powered coil would be powered by the mains, and would not need a battery.

Where a Solid State Tesla Coil (SSTC) has additional electronics, perhaps to interrupt the sparks in a musical fashion, it may be convenient to run some of the electronics off a local battery, rather than powering from the mains, but that would be choice, not a necessity.